# Show that $\{(r\cos t,r\sin t)\mid 0\leq t<\theta,r\geq 0\}$ is a borel set where $\theta$ is fixed

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $0<\theta \leq 2\pi$. Define the set $A=\{(r\cos t,r\sin t)\mid 0\leq t<\theta,r\geq 0\}$. I want to show that it is a borel set. I have drawn a figure of the set, but I am not sure if it is correct (it looks like that the domain lies in the circular sector depending on the angle $t$). At first I thought about finding an open ball that lies in $A$, but the restriction of $t$ confuses me. Is there a way of rewriting this set in terms of the intersection or union of open/closed sets?

Comment: First consider the set defined by $0 \leq t \leq \theta$, and show it is a closed set. To get the set $A$, you take the complement of a half-line where $t = \theta$; show that this half-line is also a closed set. Now that complement is not quite your set $A$ - it is missing the origin. Add (union) it back to get all of $A$. The origin is also a closed set.

Answer (score 1):

Name your set as $A$. Define the function $f : A\backslash \{(0,0)\} \to (0,\infty) \times [0,\theta)$ by $f(r\cos t,r\sin t) = (r,t)$. Note that $f$ is a continuous function : we can reparametrize it as $f(x,y) = (\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\arctan \frac yx)$, both of which remain continuous on $A$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Hence, $f$ is continuous, therefore it pulls Borel sets back to Borel sets (a standard result : every continuous function is Borel). Therefore, since $f$ is surjective, and $(0,\infty) \times [0,\theta)$ is Borel, we get that $f^{-1}((0,\infty) \times [0,\theta)) = A \backslash \{(0,0)\}$ is Borel. Naturally, $A = \{(0,0)\} \cup (A \backslash \{(0,0)\})$ is Borel, the union of two Borel sets.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set.  Let $S_q=\{(r\cos t,r\sin t): t\in [0,q]\land r\geq 0\}.$

Every $S_q$ is closed and $A=\cup \{S_q:q\in \Bbb Q \cap [0,\theta)\}.$